# empty string recognized as a double in Tcl

Tags: string, numbers, double, tcl

Why does Tcl 8.5 recognize an empty string as a double? See simple code below:

```
puts [ string is double "" ]
>1
```

I have thought that double is a well defined number.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because an entry field which is being validated character by character shouldn't be invalid when empty.

Use the `-strict` option to disallow zero-length doubles.

There are some that argue that it would have been better to have the command by default recognize valid doubles only, and instead use a flag to make the command recognize valid doubles *and* the empty string. However, in the interest of preserving compatibility, the behavior is unlikely to change in the future.

Documentation: [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: It particularly shouldn't be invalid in the transient state when you've selected everything and type in a new number, between when old number is deleted and the new number is inserted.